# SharePoint 0365 Partner Site Alerts

Tags: sharepoint

I am consulting on a SharePoint 0365 Partner Site--out of the box. Users outside my organization have access to specific Document Libraries. How do I set up Alerts so that when I upload a document to a Document Library, a designated user outside my organization will receive an e-mail notification. But when the user outside my organization uploads a file, I want an e-mail notification from that same library--the outside user does not need to receive an e-mail (which is what is happening now). Do I have to ask the outside user to set up an alert? If I set up the alert for the outside user, he gets pinged no matter who uploads a file. I would greatly appreciate any solutions to my dilemma. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using custom views and alerting on those views.

1.) Create views that filter the items in the document library based on the specific users. If you are wanting to alert other people when you upload a file, set the view to only show documents created by you, or vice-versa

[image: Custom View]

2.) Set alert on your library based on the custom view that you created. You can set the alert for the user, or ask them to create one. Just make sure you select the option to only alert on items in the view.

[image: Alerts]

Comment: Thank you so much, Alex Chance!  I'm going to try this and see how it goes! Blessings to you! --Don N.